# Sleep a layer for some seconds in cocos2dx

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I want to sleep a layer for some seconds in my game using cocos2d-x . The code is written in c++ and I will be using it for android. I dont want to stop the game completely so I can not use sleep function in c++. I have searched every where but have not  found an answer to the problem. Please help me out with it.

Answer (score 0):

Than i think only option is write that layer into some thread and using thread_sleep(time) you can chive your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
sleep(seconds);
```